# Compute the nth day from the first event in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have the following data frame, subsetted from my original data frame, with columns *event*, *unixtime*, and *day*, and I want to add another column *arbday* which is the nth day since the first event (with the first visit being day 1):

```
import numpy as np  
import datetime as dt  

>>> testdf = pd.DataFrame({'event': range(1,4), 'unixtime': [1346617885925, 1346961625305,1347214217566]},index=[343352,343353,343354])
>>> testdf['day'] = testdf['unixtime'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x/1000).date())

        event       unixtime         day   arbday
343352      1  1346617885925  2012-09-02        1
343353      2  1346961625305  2012-09-06        5
343354      3  1347214217566  2012-09-09        8
```

After looking around, I tried to do this by:

```
>>> testdf2['arbday'] = np.where(testdf2['event']==1, 1, testdf2.day.apply(lambda x: x-x[:1]))  
        event       unixtime         day   arbday
343352      1  1346617885925  2012-09-02        1
343353      2  1346961625305  2012-09-06      NaN
343354      3  1347214217566  2012-09-09      NaN

or  

>>> testdf2['arbday'] = np.where(testdf2['event']==1, 1, testdf2.day.apply(lambda x: dt.timedelta(x-x[:1])))
TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not subscriptable
```

What is the correct way to do this? Any pointer is much appreciated!

**EDIT**: A follow-up question regarding to applying this over groups is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175251/compute-the-nth-day-from-the-first-event-within-each-group-in-pandas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = DataFrame({'event': range(1,4), 'unixtime': [1346617885925, 1346961625305,1347214217566]})
df['day'] = df['unixtime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x/1000).date())
df['arbday']=df['day'].map(lambda x: (x-df.get_value(df[df.event == 1].first_valid_index(), 'day')).days+1)
print df
```

output:

```
   event       unixtime         day  arbday
0      1  1346617885925  2012-09-02       1
1      2  1346961625305  2012-09-06       5
2      3  1347214217566  2012-09-09       8
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, it doesn't work on my data frame, possibly because it's not the column _day_ is not a datetime object (although I think it should be). Please see the edits above.

Comment: Hello @root, thank you again for your update. I got it to work on the dummy data frame above, which has index 0,1,2. On my actual data frame though, it doesn't work, and this is because `df.get_value(index,col)` takes index for the first argument. The reason why it worked on the dummy data frame is that `'event'==1` is logically False, and Python associate False to 0, thus returns index[0] in this case. If you change it to `'event'=='event'`, which is logically True, it returns the second day _datetime.date(2012, 9, 6)_. I'm now trying to find a way to return the index of visit 1.

Comment: Thank you @ root, that's very helpful! As a follow-up question, how would you go about to apply the same function on groups? (See updated question). Thanks again!

Comment: @S.zhen -- you shouldn't ask "follow-up" questions by updating. if you have a new question, ask a new question. questions/answers have to remain concreete, so that they would also benefit other users, who may have a similal problem and not become a personal tutorial.

Comment: @ root, Sorry about that. I've reversed it to the original question. I'll ask my new question somewhere else. Thanks.